# How to copy (or at least SELECT) data from another SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I want to copy data from one server to another and not sure how to do that (I already have the right tables, created using `Script Table As > Create To > New Query`).

Maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI','Data Source=192.168.10.1\dbName;')
```

Or:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = '192.168.10.1'
SELECT * FROM [192.168.10.1].[dbo].[myTableName]
```

Is `IP` address (and of-course username & password..) enough ?

Comment: create a linked server and then use OPENQUERY: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: This question may be better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Addition new linkedserver & mapping between a login
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
  @server = 'your_LServer',
  @srvproduct= '',
  @provider = 'SQLNCLI',
  @datasrc= '192.168.10.1\'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
  @rmtsrvname = 'your_LServer',
  @useself = 'FALSE',
  @locallogin = 'locallogin',
  @rmtuser = 'remotelogin', 
  @rmtpassword = 'remotepassword'
```

Query againsts on linked server

```
SELECT * FROM your_LServer.dbo.myTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time, i would do go with just executing the query with data on a remote server or Linked Servers option.If it's not one time and we have to do updates in future, then we create a 'Replication' or there's a third party tool Redgate's SQL Data Compare.